# How do I fix the infinite loop creating new page error?

Tags: jasper-reports

When trying to reprint a group header on each page, I'm getting an error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Infinite loop creating new page.
```

I have already checked the option to reprint on each page and also to keep together. Are there any suggestions on why I may be receiving the error and how to fix it?